Army bootcamp or military academy tv show
I am trying to find a TV show (I think) that I used to watch on VHS as a kid (late 80's early 90's).  I believe we had recorded it onto VHS.  I believe it to be no newer than 1992, but possibly as old as 1980.  It was American, in English, live action, and in color.
What I remember:

It was either an Army training camp/boot camp, or some sort of military academy.  I think there were both men and women, and it followed a group of them, about 5-7.  I remember them wearing military fatigues.
In what was either their bunk, head quarters, or mess hall, there was
a weird cow skull on the wall.  I remember something about a guy in
the group making up a story about it being his father, or something
involving his father and the cow skull.
There is another scene where the group throw fake grenades at other people in uniform.  This was either as part of training, an attempt at a practical joke, or a distraction for them to get away with something.  The fake grenades, I believe, were either made of mud/dirt, or some sort of food stuff.
I want to say that the main characters were young, probably roughly
18 years old

It is NOT:

Stripes
The A-Team
MASH
Private Benjamin


Private Benjamin?  TV series, which was based on a movie.  Early 80's, could fit the description.

@tim nope, definitely not

Heartbreak Ridge(1986) with Clint Eastwood?  Its been a while since I've seen it, but I seem to remember some fake grenades being thrown in a training scene.

Fake grenades are staple of these movies. What specifically makes Heartbreak Ridge the right answer...especially as none of the other details fit,

no, this is not it
